# how to make ExtJS' button's background image display correctly in Extjs 2.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

I know Extjs 2.3 is pretty old but i'm taking over someone's work here.so my hands are tied for now.

well i'm supposed to change few things in the interface and add new functionality.
this is my first real ExtJS work (jquery boy here).

i wanted to add new icons on a button and it appears i can't even get the image shown correcty as i can't affect the height of the button, either on the button object property, or in css.
all that i managed to do is affect the width of the button.

here is my attempt

```
  btntelButton = new Ext.Button({
            name: 'telbtn',
            id: 'btntel',
            cls : 'x-btn-icon',
            iconCls: 'telButton',
            minWidth : 95,
        });
    <style type="text/css">
       .telButton
        {
            height: 60px;
             background-image: url(images/tel.png) !important;
        }
    </style>
```

with the use of telButton class, the backgound images comes but resized to its minimum size, showing only a small portion of the image[image: showing here]
 when i use the style on the button itself like

```
    //...
    id: 'btntel',
    cls : 'x-btn-icon',
    style: {height: '90px'}
    //...
```

it's shows [image: this]
i've been pulling my hair for the passed few hours. How would you Extjs folks do this?
please shed a light on this. Thanks for reading

Comment: To make you feel better: Ext 3.x is not much better with that. Didn't try 4.x so can't tell.

Comment: OK thanks, but like i said, it will be an overkill to migrate currently, i'm forced to use 2.3 right now. thanks

Comment: This is not really directly related to the question, nor too constructive, but:  it continues to amaze me how ExtJS, while being such a mature UI framework with considerable history and everything, still doesn't provide such a basic thing as an image button, and nobody seems to know the solution...

Comment: @ErikAllik It does: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/button/button.html

Comment: @EvanTrimboli that seems to be new in 4.1—thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

you can  add a style directly to a button

For Example:

```
style:{height:'60px'}
```

Second thought would be declaring your css class as:

```
 .telButton
  {
      height: 60px;
      background-image: url(images/tel.png) !important;
  }
```

rather than -->  button.telButton (not sure if it'll make any difference)

Comment: bruv!! i've updated my post and try your suggestion but no luck :(

Comment: hey man. you could also try re-sizing the background image to the size of the button,while using the class.

Comment: definitely not an option. not the requirement. i guess Extjs can't do it then.